# Bluetooth not working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, bluez

Somehow I have completely nuked my Bluetooth in Ubuntu 14.04 which was previously working. The issue is not it being blocked by rfkill. I tried reinstalling bluez by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove bluez
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vidplace7/bluez5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-tools
```

The out come of this was confusing. Besides totally messing up my Unity Control Centre & System Settings when i removed it (these are dependencies of bluez), this did allow me to access the Bluetooth panel in System Settings after reinstalling, but now there is nothing to show except the Bluetooth **ON** switch (which never actually stays on, as well as the ***show Bluetooth status in menu bar*** option which doesn't actually work.

It may be worth noting that there is no bluetooth device listed in `lspci`

In a desperate attempt to 'fix' things in a caveman way, I replaced all the contents of `/etc/bluetooth` with the files that were in a backup I had on a clone where everything related to Bluetooth worked fine, but I know now this was NOT the way to fix things. I now I really have messed things up.

So this then also caused major problems with my machine trying to reboot, as there was a process in usr/sbin **bluetoothd** that was preventing shutdown, which I have since renamed .bak to prevent the shutdown problem.

So now im left with a completely nuked Bluetooth. Something is terribly wrong, as I cant see any devices, or access any menus. It's just nuked. Blueman will not even work, so I know there is some serious repairs to do, however simply re-installing bluez has not resolved the issue, so im feeling very stuck.

Finally I have attempted to reinstall again with:

`sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3`

output of this install can be seen [HERE](https://paste.ubuntu.com/16017582/)

The above installs did not resolve the issue. My Bluetooth still comes up always OFF, and wont stay on, and there are simply no options to choose from.

I have also tried:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

but this never completes, just is left hanging, so I try with:

`/etc/init.d/bluetooth stop` (works fine)
`/etc/init.d/bluetooth start` then:

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth status
```

it shows it is on, but nothing is working still.

Comment: I have since re-installed a working clone where the bluetooth was working.